# Authentication popup goes into the background Selenium, Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, firefox, popupwindow

I have had the problem for 2 weeks that when I create a new Firefox driver in Selenium, the authentication popup for the proxy is immediately pushed into the background. Selenium can't reach it there anymore. Do you have a solution to the problem? I am using Selenium 3.141.5, Java 1.8. and Firefox version 63.0.1.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.sendKeys("Username" + Keys.TAB + "Password");
        alert.accept();
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
driver.get("https://www.google.de/");
```

EDIT: I tested it with Firefox version 62.0.3, everything works there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to avoid the pop-up.

1. hit Win+R, run "firefox -p" and create new profile (let's call it selenium_profile)
2. run Firefox in selenium_profile, login to the proxy and save your credetials to Firefox
3. use the customized profile, there is my setup:

   ```
   FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
   ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();         
   FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium_profile");
   options.setProfile(selenium_profile);
   options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", sec_var.driver_path);
   driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   ```

With custom browser profile you can use almost any settings modification, imported certificate (to avoid another auth pop-up), use extensions, ...

Basic auth pop-up you can avoid with send credentials in URL:

```
driver.get("https://username:password@www.example.com");
```

but it does not work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I have the **exact same problem** and have been researching everywhere for a workaround.

*Here is what I've learned so far*:

- Using the previously saved `custom browser profile` that keeps your credentials saved (@pburgr suggestion) does the trick, however it also accumulates a lot more unintended and possibly undesired browser profile informations such as cookies, history and everything.
- the auth pop up is not a normal pop up so it cannot be manipulated with selenium switch_to
- In addition these type of credential pop ups cannot be inspected nor javascripted.
- Another workaround is to use pyAutoGui to alt+tab and fill your credentials. Not a great solution though because you may have trouble into guessing how many alt+tabs until the pop up.

Bottomline: The most promising way would be loading a fresh clean browser profile, updating this profile by adding such credentials (I don't know how nor if feasible) and voilà, discarding this profile at the end of the session.